# Failure to connect to Azure Service bus queue

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, azure-servicebus-queues, .net-core-2.1

Am trying to listen to an azure service bus queue
but am getting an exception when initializing the connection to to the queue.
I have tried to search for a way out but with less success.
Note that am using .NETCore 2.1.
This is how am initializing the connection it:

```
// Initialize the connection to Service Bus Queue
_queueClient = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(_interswitchQueueConnectionString, _interswitchQueueName, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```

And this the exception am getting:

> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 
>   'Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Constants' threw an exception. --->
>   System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.UriTemplate'
>   from assembly 'System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.Constants..cctor()
>       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder..ctor()
>       at Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(String
>   connectionString, String path, ReceiveMode mode)

The same initialization works fine when using .net framework.
How can I do it in .NetCore ?
Please Help
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With .NET Core you should use the new .NET Standard Azure Service Bus client, [Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/). The old client [WindowsAzure.ServiceBus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.ServiceBus/) is a legacy client, only works with Full Framework, and is **not** recommended moving forward.

The new client does not have a concept of factory. You're in charge of creating entity clients ([`QueueClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient?view=azure-dotnet), [`SubscriptionClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.subscriptionclient?view=azure-dotnet), and [`TopicClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.topicclient?view=azure-dotnet)) and managing connections.

Comment: How can you make `CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting` work when using `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` / .NET Core?  I can't seem to find a straight answer anywhere.

Comment: `CloudConfigurationManager` is a legacy configuration API. You should look into alternatives. Also, not entirely sure how this is related to the answer 

Comment: Oh, yeah, I guess I was tired earlier and kind of threw the two in the same category.

Answer (score 2):

On Dotnet Core 2.1 you can try this.

```
var queueClient = new QueueClient(connectionString, entityPath, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Muhammed, I figured out that I had to use the IQueueClient to get this done, I had to use Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using MessagingFactory

```
MessagingFactory factory = MessagingFactory.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString);

            queueClient = await factory.CreateMessageReceiverAsync(_entityPath, ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete);
```

Comment: This requires WindowsAzure.ServiceBus, and as @Sean Feldman said, it only works with Full Framework. I get a FileNotFoundException when trying to use MessagingFactory in Dotnet Core 2.1